# How to use tocloft to create a list which appears in the middle of the document

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, minitoc

I have a document in IEEE (conf) format and I want to add a new environment using `tocloft`. The relevant code looks like this (slightly abbreviated):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{List of Examples}
% FIXME: Should be styled as a "normal" subsection
\newlistof{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}
% FIXME: Remove page numbers
\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{examples}
  \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}
  {\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example}: #1}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\example{A first example}
\listofexamples
\end{document}
```

And the result looks something like this:

[image: Output of the code above]

Despite using the `titles` option with `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` the heading for the list of examples looks like a `\section*` rather than a `\section`. This makes sense as a default, usually a table would be generated as part of the front matter of a book. However, I would like that heading to be a normal `\section` since it will appear in the middle of the document. Is this possible?

Secondly, how can the page numbers against each item in the `\listofexamples` be removed, so only the examples themselves are listed?

Comment: I think `minitoc` package is of more use here

Comment: Thanks. I had a brief look at the `minitoc` documentation. I can see how it would work for reformatting a list of figures or a ToC, but I couldn't see how it could be used for a completely new list. Have I missed something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of this question can be resolved by incrementing the `section` counter automatically and inserting it into the table title manually, like this:

```
\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{\addtocounter{section}{1}\thesection.~List of Examples}
```

The second part of this question (how to remove the page numbers) can be answered by using the `\cftpagenumbersoff{XXX}` macro (where `XXX` is the long-form name of the new list).

In this case the corrected code looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{\addtocounter{section}{1}\thesection.~List of Examples}

\newlistof[section]{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}

\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{examples}
  \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}
  {\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example \theexamples}: #1}

\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3.0em}
\cftpagenumbersoff{examples} % Don't print page numbers with examples
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm} % Add space around example numbers
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That the first part of the question requires such a hack method to solve is really unfortunate. `tocloft` is set up to define its very own heading formatting, and `titles` simply turns that off to use whatever is defined by the class (e.g. `\section*`). So there's no way within `tocloft` (yet) to change that to an unstarred section.

I've added an [issue](https://github.com/wspr/herries-press/issues/24) in its Github page to address this.

To get this working now, you can redefine the `\listofexamples` command: (its definition is fairly understandable)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listofexamples{%
  \@cfttocstart
  \if@cfthaschapter
    \chapter{\listexampletitle}%
  \else
    \section{\listexampletitle}%
  \fi
  \@nameuse{cftmarkexp}%
  \@starttoc{exp}%
  \@cfttocfinish 
}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, the `\patchcmd` command from `toolbox` is really good for this sort of fix:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\listofexamples{\section*}{\section}{}{}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, Will. The answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198333/10579) also recommends using `etoolbox` to resolve what I now realise is the same problem. Great to here that you've added the problem to the package Issues list.