# tocloft cross-references a section as a subsection

Tags: cross-referencing, tocloft

I have document which creates a new list of examples. The list has a label `\label{sec:examples}` which labels the title of the list, which is rendered as a section. However, cross referencing `sec:examples` results in a reference to a subsection.

This is a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{\addtocounter{section}{1}\thesection.~List of Examples\label{sec:examples}}

\newlistof[section]{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}

\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{examples}
  \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}
  {\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example \theexamples}: #1}

\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3.0em}
\cftpagenumbersoff{examples}
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm}


\begin{document}

\title{Example IEEE with tocleft}

\author{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Examples are summarised in Section \ref{sec:examples}.

\example{A first example}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1]{}
\example{A second example}

\listofexamples

\end{document}
```

A picture of the relevant output is below, with the problematic line highlighted in yellow. The first line of the Introduction, which is rendered as:

```
Examples are summarised in Section II.I.
```

should read:

```
Examples are summarised in Section III.
```

How do I correct this?

Output:

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar: I agree with your objection about the placement of the label, but your suggestion would reference the first section however!

Comment: @HarishKumar: I think, we have a misunderstanding... I believe, the OP just wants to add a reference to the 'section' where the list appears.

Comment: That's right, it's the list that needs to be referenced, not any particular example. I have added an image of the PDF to clarify.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes I misunderstood! :-(

Comment: @snim2 Your demand of `Examples are summarised in Section II.` should have been `Examples are summarised in Section III.` with regard to the current picture as List of Examples is `III` not `II`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: No problem...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not my fault though as OP mislead me ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow the `\newlistof` command seems to group (didn't check this, admittedly) the `\refstepcounter` command within. It's better to patch the `\listofexamples`, first stepping the section counter, than immediately correcting it back by decreasing it. 
This is achieved by the `etoolbox` package command `\pretocmd`, which is done in this case a little lazy, I ignored the tests ;-)

I changed the definition of `\listofexamples` etc. a little bit, making it a true section.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{List of Examples}


\newlistof[section]{examples}{exp}{\section{\listexampletitle}}%

% Prepending the \listofexamples command with dummy \refstepcounter{section} etc.
\pretocmd{\listofexamples}{\refstepcounter{section}\addtocounter{section}{-1}}{}{}%



\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{examples}%
  \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}%
  {\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
}%

\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example \theexamples}: #1}

\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3.0em}%
\cftpagenumbersoff{examples}
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm}


\begin{document}

\title{Example IEEE with tocleft}

\author{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Examples are summarised in Section \ref{sec:examples}.

\example{A first example}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1]{}
\example{A second example}



\listofexamples\label{sec:examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @snim2: Please test it, give feedback later on -- I will return to it on problems, but for now I am off ;-)