# list of newcounter

Tags: table-of-contents, counters, tocloft

I've set up a `newcounter` in a LaTeX document:

```
\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
```

so that I can reference them throughout my document:

```
\begin{example}[title]
This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}
```

my question is, **how can I generate a list of all my examples?** In a similar way to a list of figures, I was hoping I could get a list of examples, with their titles, and the page number they appear on. **Is this possible?**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look into `tocloft` package and its `\newlistof` command. See also this recent question, where some example is shown http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198326/tocloft-cross-references-a-section-as-a-subsection. Perhaps, you should use a `theorem`-like environment from `amsthm` etc. for the framework of your example as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 'quick and dirty' solution, with `\newlistof` command from `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcounter{example}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{example}}%
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%  
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    }{%
      \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}{\protect\numberline{\theexample}#1}%
    }%
  \par\medskip%
  \noindent\textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}%




\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{List of Examples}

\newlistof[section]{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}%

\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3.0em}%
%\cftpagenumbersoff{examples}
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}%

\listofexamples


\begin{example}[title]

This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}


\begin{example}
This is the 2nd  example, but has no entry to the toc!
\end{example}


\section{A section}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{example}[Another title]
\blindtext[2] 

Another example.
\end{example}


\begin{example}[Yet Another title]
\blindtext[3]% 

Yet Another example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Another version without section numbers for examples

*Disclaimer* I do not recommend dropping the section number for examples, as it will lead to more difficult identification which example is meant, especially if examples have the same title (due to some reason)

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{example}}% To be on the safe side!
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%  
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    }{%
      \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}{\protect\numberline{\theexample}#1}%
    }%
  \par\medskip%
  \noindent\textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}%




\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{List of Examples}

\newlistof[section]{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}%

\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3em}% Some indentation -- change to 0pt if needed
%\cftpagenumbersoff{examples}
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm}%


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}%

\listofexamples


\begin{example}[title]

This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}


\begin{example}
This is the 2nd  example, but has no entry to the toc!
\end{example}


\section{A section}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{example}[Another title]
\blindtext[2] 

Another example.
\end{example}


\begin{example}[Yet Another title]
\blindtext[3]% 

Yet Another example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Seems to work pretty well to me! Two questions: 1) Why do you consider it dirty, is it not the "ideal" solution? 2) Could we change it so that the identifier excludes the section it's in? And it just incremented by one regardless of which section it's in?

Comment: @MrGoobri: It's not really *dirty*, but fast, there might be better approaches. If you mean *exclude*, you say, e.g. `Another title` instead of `2.1 Another title` and you want to have continous counting, without any resetting?

Comment: @MrGoobri: See my updated/alternative answer (I hope, I understood your requests correctly)

Comment: That's great thanks @christian-hupfer but I would still like to see the example number in list if possible. So from your example above, I would like to see 1 title....1; 2 Another title.....1; 3 Yet another title.....2.

Comment: @MrGoobri: You want to see in the list, but not in the example in place, where it appears?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm not clear. What I'm looking for in the main body, for instance, is: Example 1: title1 _more text_ Example 2: title2 _more text_ Example 3: title3. Then, in the list, I'm looking for: 1 title1.......1, 2 title2.........5, 3 title3......7 - Where the number after all the dots is the page number, and the number before the title is the example number. Does that make more sense? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @MrGoobri: Sorry, next confusion: *number before all the dots is the page number* --- **Before** or **after** -- if after, my last example is perhaps what you want

Comment: Quite correct. I made a mistake, sorry. The last one is perfect. Thank you for all your help. I've learnt a lot! :)

Comment: @MrGoobri: Ok -- that's what TeX.SX is designed for. Happy TeXing in future! You're welcome!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  can you explain plz how I can add space between examples of different chapters

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to do with the `ntheorem` package: I define `example` as a new theorem, whose counter is reset at each section, and then use the `\listtheorems{example}` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, x11names]{article}%]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}%

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\mdseries}
\theoremseparator{.}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\newcommand\listofexamples{\section*{List of Examples}\listtheorems{example}}

\begin{document}

\section{A First Section}

\begin{example}[Title]
This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Title the Second]
This is the second example of the first section.
\end{example}

\section{Another Section}

\begin{example}[Title title]
This is the first example of the second section. The counter was reset.
\end{example}

\listofexamples

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use package tocbasic coming with
KOMA-script. You can easily set up a floating environment (or a
nonfloating if you want to) using simple key-value pairs. All the
listof-macros you know are there. The list will look just like
your list of figures and tables (if you modified them a safe
way).

You can style the environment using, for example, the caption
package. If you are using package hyperref and its \autoref
functionality, surprise ... works as well :-)

If you are resetting the counter each section, `\thecounter` will
be longer making the output look ugly. Package `tocstyle` and it
`tocautoindent` feature come to help. You need a few LaTeX runs
till the needed space is calculated correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=example,
    counterwithin=section,
    float,
    %nonfloat, %If you don't want them to float
    name=Example,
    listname={List of Examples},
]{xpl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofexamples\clearpage

\section{Introduction}%
\begin{example}
    \caption{title}
This is the first example. The counter will be reset at each section.
\end{example}


\begin{example}
    \caption{example with ducks}
    Duck and cover!
\end{example}


\section{Quack}
Ducks are quite nice creatures, find a picture of a duck in
\autoref{xpl:duck}.
\blindtext[1]
\begin{example}
    \caption{More Ducks}
    \label{xpl:duck}
\blindtext[2] 
\rule{5cm}{2cm}
Another example.
\end{example}


\begin{example}
    \caption{funny penguins}
\blindtext[3]% 

Yet Another example.
\end{example}
\begin{figure}
\caption{figure}
\caption{figure}
\caption{figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: mrgooniList]

*Using standard hyperref to show the link*

[image: mrgoobiAutoref]

Comment: Works well for floating, but note that `nonfloat` didn't work for me.

Comment: @jk What exactly doesn't work? If you use nonfloat, you have to omit float. Maybe asking a new question (including a link to this answer) might be a good idea.

Comment: It should be noted, that package tocstyle is obsolete now.