# Change name of table in caption and reference

Tags: tables, input

I have multiple tables in my thesis with model results. I want to change these tables' names, meaning it wouldn't say `Table 1` but `Model 1` (also when referencing them). Also, a special table of content for them would be nice.

I get the model output as a `.tex`-file and include it with `\input`:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Example Model}
    \label{model:example_model}
    \input{../models/example}
\end{table}
```

Is this *easily* doable? I've searched a bit for this, but to be honest: I don't really know what to look for.

Any hint is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit: I also have other tables in my document, so I assume that changing the whole table-class is not an option.

Comment: Please have a look at [Using KOMA-Script packages with other classes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218964) and [list of newcounter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198957)

Comment: a very similar question was asked regarding floats, and the answer appears to be relevant to tables too: [New figure environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6478/579).

Comment: Thanks bot of you for your input. I ended up using `newfloat` as suggested in one of the answers in  Barbara's links and it works like a charm.