# Creating a listofX that is not a TOC

Tags: xetex

I am currently using `tocloft` to carry a list counter for recommendations that I drop into the summary page. It's pretty ugly and I actually manually convert the output to a list for release, but it's useful so that I can automatically track all the items.

What I would like to do is have a counter running that can be used to build an itemize list. Something like:

[image]

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
    \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{summary}
    \subsection{Examples}
    %
    % I would like this list to be generated from a command like \listofExample
    %
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first example
        \item second example
    \end{itemize}
\section{some body text}
Lorizzle ipsum dolor sure amizzle, consectetizzle adipiscing elit. Own yo' sapizzle that's the shizzle, aliquet volutpat, suscipizzle gangsta, gravida dang, owned. Pellentesque crazy tortizzle. Sed erizzle. That's the shizzle at dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle break yo neck, yall. Tellivizzle fo shizzle nibh yo yippiyo. Dawg izzle . Sizzle eleifend rhoncizzle bling bling. In hac its fo rizzle platea dictumst. Sheezy go to hizzle. Curabitizzle tellus urna, pretizzle eu, mattis sizzle, eleifend vitae, nunc. Away daahng dawg. Integizzle rizzle hizzle sizzle break yo neck, yall.
    \example{first example}
Dizzle shizznit dolizzle. Fusce magna , dignissizzle sizzle amet, i'm in the shizzle egizzle, sollicitudizzle dizzle, tortor. Boofron hizzle nisi. Cool malesuada neque izzle phat. Suspendisse ma nizzle. Mah nizzle da bomb tristique turpizzle. Suspendisse blandit ultrices purizzle. Sizzle dolor libero, yo interdizzle, posuere ut, dapibizzle izzle, yo mamma. Suspendisse sheezy tellus. Check it out gangsta lectus sizzle gangster dolor. Black dapibizzle gizzle brizzle mofo. Lorem tellivizzle dolizzle crunk amizzle, shiznit adipiscing elizzle. Suspendisse rizzle purus, eleifend laoreet, things id, fo shizzle nizzle, elit. Nizzle mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rutrizzle dawg.
    \example{second example}
\end{document}
```

Digging through `tocloft` source code looks...difficult... Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is as close as I could get to what I was looking for..

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{Recommendations}
\newlistof{examples}{exp}{\subsection{\listexampletitle}}

\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{examples}
    \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}{\textbullet~#1}%fake an itemize list by pushing textbullets in - if you use other bullets you need to change this
}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example} \theexamples{}: #1}
\cftsetindents{examples}{1.5em}{3.0em}
\cftpagenumbersoff{examples} % Don't print page numbers with examples
\setlength{\cftexamplesnumwidth}{1.5cm} % Add space around example numbers

\begin{document}
    
    \section{summary}
    \listofexamples
\section{some body text}
Lorizzle ipsum dolor sure \example{first example}
Dizzle shizznit dolizzle. 
    \example{second example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now if I compile your code I see the list...that is also a pointed list ;) very good!!

Comment: well it looks like an itemize list.. but its not :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sketch

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexampletitle}{List of Examples}
\newlistof{examples}{exp}{\listexampletitle}
\newcommand{\examplelist}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{examples}
  \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}{Example \protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\examplelist{#1}\textbf{Example} \theexamples{}: #1}

\begin{document}
\section{summary}
Lorizzle ipsum dolor sure amizzle...

\listofexamples

\section{some body text}
Lorizzle ipsum dolor sure amizzle...

\example{}
Dizzle shizznit dolizzle...

\example{}
Dizzle shizznit dolizzle...
\end{document}
```

...and [here is my source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197369/49683). This solution involves the use of the package [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

The *list* is generated by the code within the header, then you can move the command `\listofexamples` and its output wherever you want in your document.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work... it gives a TOC style list, not an itemize style list.. but I'll have a look at the source

Comment: Edited your code so that it generates a list... but not an itemize type list..The next challenge is to generate a list like the desired example :)

Comment: @baradhili I do not get the expected output compiling your version of the code... Unrelated, you might want to add another different answer :)